# How do I update from ASP.Net Core 2.2.0 to 3 using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

How do I upgrade .Net Core 2.2.0 to 3.0 in Visual Studio Code?

Do I use this command below?

> dotnet tool update Package_id

from this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-update)?

Reason - .Net Core 3 has the "System.Text.Json" built in Json Serializer, and I need to use it!

Comment: Not sure, haven't looked at all the differences. I just need a serializer/deserializer that can be used on complex objects. And speed isn't that important...

Comment: Do you recommend I just install JSON.Net?

Comment: JSON.NET is already integrated with ASP.NET Core 2.0 (you can configure it via `.AddJsonOptions` off `services.AddMvc()`). It does seem that [System.Text.Json](https://michaelscodingspot.com/the-battle-of-c-to-json-serializers-in-net-core-3/) is a little more performant, however. I think either is a good choice, although there's no reason not to go with .NET Core 3 and stay current. As for your question, I'm afraid I don't have an answer since I do everything through Visual Studio (i.e. not VS Code).

Comment: In worst case, generate a .NET Core 3.0 project and cut/paste what's needed. There is no one command upgrade, due to so many changes in 3.x.